# How to swich the color theme in WinUI3 manually?

Tags: c#, xaml, winui-3

I want to build a combobox to let user choose which theme they want the app to display.

I added a combobox on my WinUI projects's settings page
The code go like this:

```
<!--XAML CODE-->

<ComboBox x:Name="themeMode" SelectionChanged="Themes_SelectionChanged">
    <ComboBoxItem>Light</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Dark</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Defaut</ComboBoxItem>                    
</ComboBox>
```

But I don't know how to defined "Themes_SelectionChanged"
*(I have found some ways, but I think they're too complex to implement just this simple functionality, aren't there any simple way to acieve this?)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say this ComboBox is in **MainPage.xaml**.

```xml
<ComboBox x:Name="themeMode" SelectionChanged="Themes_SelectionChanged">
    <ComboBoxItem>Light</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Dark</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Defaut</ComboBoxItem>                    
</ComboBox>
```

then in **MainPage.xaml.cs**

```cs
private void Themes_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is ComboBox comboBox &&
        comboBox.SelectedItem is ComboBoxItem comboBoxItem &&
        comboBoxItem.Content is string themeString &&
        Enum.TryParse(themeString, out ElementTheme theme) is true)
    {
        this.RequestedTheme = theme;
    }
}
```

Also, instead of manually adding items in XAML, you can do it this way.

In **MainPage.xaml**:

```cs
public ImmutableArray<string> ElementThemeOptions { get; } = ImmutableArray.Create(Enum.GetNames<ElementTheme>());

private void Themes_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is ComboBox comboBox &&
        comboBox.SelectedValue is string themeString &&
        Enum.TryParse(themeString, out ElementTheme theme) is true)
    {
        this.RequestedTheme = theme;
    }
}
```

And in **MainPage.xaml**:

```xml
<ComboBox
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind ElementThemeOptions}"
    SelectionChanged="Themes_SelectionChanged" />
```

**UPDATE**

Don't forget to do this in the root page, `MainPage` in this case.

```xml
<Window
    ...
    ...>
    <local:MainPage />
</Window>
```

Comment: Sorry, English is not my native language, so the expression may be a little unclear. And, yes, that's basically what I'm trying to say

Comment: It works! But what else if my ComboBox is in an Expander, how can I modify the code so that its selection works for the entire window?

Comment: It should work as long as `this` is the root page, which should be the content of  your `MainWindow`.

Comment: If this solved your problem, please accept the answer so we can close this session.

Comment: Thanks, this sloved my problem

Comment: @WuXiuheng Can you flag this somehow so that others can find the workable solution easily?